# Symfony2 - A proper way to manage cache in production

Tags: caching, symfony, production-environment

I have seen several posts about production cache management but I'm trying to get the proper way.

I have seen some pretty `sudo chmod 777 app/cache app/log` and even `sudo chmod 777 ../my_project_root` :)

I don't want to use the chmod technique. I think it's better to `chown www-data` cache and log folders.

Now the question is:
When I need to clear the cache in my production server it's told to use:

```
$ sudo php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

But it seems to chown the prod cache folder back to root.

How should I properly clear the cache of my production server ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sudo -u www-data php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

Comment: First time I see that. It seems simple and straight forward. Thank you. I will accept in 10 minutes :)

Comment: Probably because you think  that `su` means "superuser"? ;) A common mistake. `su` means "substitute user" and with `-u` you give it the username of the user you want to use as substitute for yourself. `sudo` is like `su`, but for a single command.

Answer (score 3):

If you take a look at the [Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html) documentation, there are a few commands you can launch to manage cache and log directories:

```
sudo setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwx -m u:`whoami`:rwx app/cache app/logs
sudo setfacl -dR -m u:www-data:rwx -m u:`whoami`:rwx app/cache app/logs
```

In my opinion this is the cleanest method.

*NB: If you choose this method, don't forget to activate ACLs on your partition*

Comment: This allows me to do `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod` getting rid of the sudo isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, this way you don't need to sudo

Comment: Ok thank you, that's what I though. I am personally not able to use ACLs because I don't have rights to change fstab. But this seems indeed to be the best way.